# Wordpress WP_Query orderby being overwritten

Tags: wp-query, order

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'mcm_company',
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '1000',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
);
$r = array();       
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I'm expected to see the results get returned in alphabetical order, but it's not. The final query is

```
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'mcm_company' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 1000
```

which you can see is getting the wrong `ORDER BY`. I'm assuming something is overwriting the `orderby`... is there a way to force the order to title?

---

The issue was from the Post Types Order plugin, with the Auto Sort option enabled

Comment: I haven't written any, but it's possible maybe another plugin is.. Is there a way to force the orderby, or do a final filter override? or a way to see where it might be coming from?

Comment: I was hoping not to have to, but I will try that next. thanks

Comment: I just try your code on a clean WordPress version 4.8.2 and I obtain `'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = \'mcm_company\' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = \'publish\'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 1000'`

Comment: Narrowed it down, it was because I'm using the Post Types Order plugin, and had the Auto Sort option enabled.

Comment: above comment helped me tracing the issue, it was the plugin that was adding the order by menu_order .

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the following code before running new WP_Query:

```
remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
```

This will prevent other entities like plugins to alter the 'ORDERBY' parameter via the 'posts_orderby' filter.

Comment: I like this answer because you don't need to remove/disable the plugin. In my case it's an old site that I took over and have no idea what the plugin's purpose is, so I didn't want to remove it just yet